# How common is Imperfect Subjunctive in modern German?

Tags: grammar-identification, subjunctive, preterite

I'm currently reading [Remarque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erich_Maria_Remarque)'s *"[Im Westen nichts Neues](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Im_Westen_nichts_Neues)"* (*"[All Quiet on the Western Front](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Quiet_on_the_Western_Front)"* in [Wheen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Wheen)'s  translation) and came across the word "säßen." I found out this is the Imperfect Subjunctive of "sitzen." Here is the direct quote from the novel:

> Leicht hätte es sein können, daß wir heute nicht
> auf unsern Kästen säßen, es war verdammt nahe daran. Und darum
> ist alles neu und stark—der rote Mohn und das gute Essen, die
> Zigaretten und der Sommerwind

What I want to know is if this still used much today? My guess is when speaking, someone would just say "würden...sitzen" or "hätten...gesessen" instead, and perhaps even write that in a book too. Is this assumption correct? Or do mostly northern Germans use the Imperfect Subjunctive in speech?

The reason I ask is this book is somewhat old and has a lot of contextual words that I can tell are out of date or not really used much. So my assumption is that this form of grammar is also a bit old fashioned.

Comment: "Imperfect" does not exist in German. Past tense, Präteritum.

Comment: "würden...gesitzt" or "hätten...gesitzt" – The past participle of *sitzen* is *gesessen*, not *gesitzt*. It would be either *würden sitzen* or *hätten gesessen*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's commonly called *Konjunktiv II*. Another name is *Konjunktiv Präteritum* but forget about that one as it's confusing. *Imperfect Subjunctive* is technically the same but an even more confusing name that is unknown in German.

Konjunktiv II forms are commonly used with the auxiliaries and the modals.

It's less common to use those forms for strong verbs as e.g. *sitzen*, and completely uncommon to use them for weak verbs as they cannot be distinguished from Präteritum forms for those. Instead *würden+Infinitiv* is used. That's technically Konjunktiv II Futur I but it means the same as Konjunktiv II in German.

Answer (score 6):

Dem Satz

> Leicht hätte es sein können, dass wir heute nicht auf unsern Kästen **säßen**, es war verdammt nahe daran.

sieht man sein Alter nicht an. Diese Art der Formulierung ist heute nach wie vor gültig.

Was man häufig stattdessen hört, ist:

> Leicht hätte es sein können, dass wir heute nicht auf unsern Kästen **sitzen würden**, es war verdammt nahe daran.

aber war es zur Zeit, als der Text verfasst wurde, wahrscheinlich auch schon. Über Unterschiede zwischen Nord- und Süddeutschen ist mir in der Hinsicht nichts bekannt.

Comment: Meines Erachtens vor allem ein Unterschied zwischen Schrift- und gesprochener Sprache. Auch wenn das Buch in der 1. Person geschrieben ist.

Answer (score 4):

The use of subjunctive in such a subordinate clause is indeed fairly uncommon today. Even *würden* would usually not be used, because the irreality is already expressed by the subjunctive II in the main clause.

Today, *säßen* or *sitzen würden*  would usually only be used the subclause were followed by some condition ("dass wir heute nicht mehr auf unseren Kästen säßen/sitzen würden, wenn..."). What you would most likely read today is:

> Leicht hätte es sein können, daß wir heute nicht auf unsern Kästen sitzen, es war verdammt nahe dran.

Comment: No, it's not missing. Indicative is OK here.

Comment: I disagree with your sentiment that _würden_ would not be used today in that sentence. It really sounds wrong to me in present tense.

Answer (score 3):

To gibe an answer from somebody who studied literature not linguistics: The novel is unusual in itself because it is written past tense but in historical present. This means it uses present tense for a stylistic purpose when actually past tense is required from a logical point of view.

If this was written in past tense modern it would have to be shifted to Konjunktiv perfekt which is very much common.

> Leicht hätte es [so gewesen] sein können, daß wir heute nicht auf unsern Kästen gesessen hätten, es war verdammt nahe daran [gewesen]. Und darum war alles neu und stark.

This is everyday language for a reasonably educated German. Whether you call Remarque's style old-fashioned or artsy is up to you.